# Python - Sprite chasing another sprite

Tags: python, oop, pygame, sprite

I'm developing a "Space Invaders like" game using `pygame`. At the moment my code is functional and I've finished the game basics.
So now I'd like to make the enemies move toward my player, here is my code:

```
class createShip(imports.pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        imports.pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = loader.joueur_image
        self.rect = loader.joueur_rect
        self.rect.x = constantes.screen_width/2 - self.rect.width/2
        self.rect.y = constantes.screen_height - self.rect.height - 20

    def update(self):
        if (imports.pygame.key.get_pressed()[imports.pygame.K_LEFT] == True):
            self.rect.x -= constantes.speed_ship
        elif (imports.pygame.key.get_pressed()[imports.pygame.K_RIGHT] == True):
            self.rect.x += constantes.speed_ship
        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
        elif self.rect.x > constantes.screen_width - self.rect.width:
            self.rect.x = constantes.screen_width - self.rect.width

class createEnemy(imports.pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        imports.pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = imports.pygame.Surface([50, 50])
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = 0
        self.rect.x = imports.random.randint(constantes.screen_width/2 - 350, constantes.screen_width/2 + 350)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += imports.random.randint(constantes.speed_enemy - 8, constantes.speed_enemy + 2)
        if self.rect.y > constantes.screen_height - 35:
            self.rect.y = 0
            self.rect.x = imports.random.randint(constantes.screen_width/2 - 350, constantes.screen_width/2 + 350)
```

Here is my problem. I don't want to code the moving part inside my game loop, it is simpler to call the sprite update method.
So I was hoping to call my ship class inside my enemy class to get `ship.rect.x` and `ship.rect.y`, but obviously it didn't work because my ship object isn't created.

I can't find a way to get my ship coordinates inside my enemy class. I thought of doing another inheritance, but there must be an easier way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I answering because I don't have the reputation to comment, otherwise i would have commented) 
I'm going to have the same problem very soon for a program I'm writing.
My guess is to istantiate the player and then pass the variable that refer to the istance to the CreateEnemey class as a parameter, something along these lines:

```
class createShip(imports.pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        imports.pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        pass

class createEnemy(imports.pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player):
        imports.pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x_player = player.rect.x
        self.y_player = player.rect.y
```

Then, before the loop starts:

```
player = createShip()
```

I have actually did this before and it works, just not by subclassing pygame.sprite.Sprite (I had created my own Player class).